# saving gnuplot figure without displaying the plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file (data.txt). I can plot the data with using gnup command. Like;

```
gnup -p data.txt -xl 'Hours' -yl 'Data (m)'
```

I need to save the plot (for example png format) after executing above command without plotting the data. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by _without plotting the data_? Without displaying?

Comment: yes without displaying.

Comment: I don't find any `gnup` command with standard installation. what was that? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: What exactly is `gnup`? is it some alias of your own? Normally, you'd plot directly to file by setting the gnuplot `term` (or `terminal`) to the desired output file type e.g. `set term png` or `set term pdfcairo`. Run `set term` (without any arguments) at the gnuplot prompt to get a complete list of the available terminal types on your system

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415671/gnuplot-do-not-show-graph-after-saving-into-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnuplot` has a `set output` command that I use to save a copy of my plot:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Run this script after synching the Palm with $HOME/Visor/.last

# Weight - extract my weight data fron the Visor, clean it
# up, and feed it to gnuplot

target=$HOME/Visor/var/Weight
visorhome="$HOME/Visor"
gnuplotdata="${target}.pltdata"
gnuplotout="${target}.ps"

# ... data prep omitted - data to plot is in $gnuplotdata 

gnuplot <<EOF
set title "Weight and running average, in kilograms, for Walt Sullivan"
set timefmt "%y/%m/%d"
set xdata time
set format x "%y/%m/%d"
plot "$gnuplotdata" using 1:2 with linespoints, "" using 1:3 with linespoints;
pause 10 "Plot will close in 10 seconds, see $gnuplotout"
set terminal postscript enhanced color landscape
set output "$gnuplotout"
replot
EOF

exit 0
```

To learn more, type:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> help set output
 By default, screens are displayed to the standard output. The `set output`
 command redirects the display to the specified file or device.
...
```